# WPF MVVM DataGrid refresh when new row in database table

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

i want to refresh DataGrid automatically when from another application add new row to the database table. I'm using ObservableCollection, but it does not work. I'm using EntitityFramework, code first. Please help me!

**View:**

```
xmlns:wm="clr-namespace:Admin.ViewModels"

<Window.DataContext>
        <wm:IncidentViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid
                x:Name="DataGridIncidenty" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ColumnWidth="*"
                MouseDoubleClick="Row_DoubleClick"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="5,5,5,0"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
                                   TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, 
                                   ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
                filter:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Incidents, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectedIndex="0">                
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="HostName" Binding="{Binding Computer.Hostname}" Width="auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding TextIncident}" Width="*">
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**ModelView:**

```
namespace Admin.ViewModels
{
    class IncidentViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Incident> _incidents;
        public ObservableCollection<Incident> Incidents
        {
            get { return _incidents; }
            set 
            {
                _incidents = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Incidents");
            }
        }

        public IncidentViewModel()
        {
            CC_RK2Entities context = new CC_RK2Entities();
            Incidents = new ObservableCollection<Incident>(context.Incident);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which database do you use? A server or a File?

Comment: I'm using SQL server database

Comment: Well maybe you could have a look at this tutorial? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server

Comment: Entity Framework will not pick up any insertions of rows from a different application, you will have to execute the query.

Comment: @MikeEason thats right, but the correct way would be just to update the Model from the database right? Here's the problem that the application has to notice when the database changes, and thats why i posted the above tutorial

Comment: @JoshuadV I'm not entirely sure, he just needs to execute the query to get the records again. Knowing when to do that is the problem. I'm not sure exactly what that tutorial is doing to be honest, although it seems legit, so it's probably worth a try.

Comment: @MikeEason yes thats right. I dont know too, but yes i think it worths a try. In Android it would be easy, the other app could just notify his application when she changes something :/

Comment: @JoshuadV - thanks this tutorial looking good, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @RadovanKozák Great thanks, good luck! If it works i'll save it, because thats a sceneria i could use sometimes :)